# SQL Data Source - store procedure and return parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldatasource

I have a store procedure in SQL Server which returns a value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertProc]
    @value1 INT,
    @value2 INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO table1(value1,value2) VALUES (@value1,@value2)

    RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

I connect to the DB from ASP.NET using SQL Data Source, which is configured like this:

```
InsertCommand="@insertedId = insertProc"
InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure"

oninserting="sqlDS_Inserting" 
oninserted="sqlDS_Inserted"

<InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="value1" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="value2" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="insertedId" DbType="Int32" Direction="ReturnValue" />
</InsertParameters>
```

What I want to do it to get the returned value. In the body of `sqlDS_Inserted` procedure I do like this:

```
this.insertedId = Convert.ToInt32(e.Command.Parameters["insertedId"].Value);
```

but I get error:

```
Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
```

However, when I look at SQL Server Profiler and run the command (adding declaration of @insertedId variable) it works good. What is the problem and how can I get the returned value of stored procedure from ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this statement is your problem.

```
InsertCommand="@insertedId = insertProc"
```

You don't need to explicitly assign the return value of the stored procedure to the return value parameter. Just specify the name of the stored procedure.

```
 InsertCommand = "InsertProc"
```

Another thing is that you will have to precede the parameter name in your `OnInserted` event handler with '@'.

```
this.insertedId = Convert.ToInt32(e.Command.Parameters["@insertedId"].Value);
```

Comment: Unfortunately you are right! I was trying with and without @insertedId on the beginning (and many other options), with or without @ in OnInserted, but I think I never tried in this configuration. Anyway, thanks. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{ 
    SqlConnection conMyData = default(SqlConnection); 
    SqlCommand cmdInsert = default(SqlCommand); 
    SqlParameter parmReturnValue = default(SqlParameter); 
    long l = 0; 

    conMyData = new SqlConnection(_SQLDBConnString); 
    cmdInsert = new SqlCommand("insEmployee", conMyData); 

    { 
        cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
        parmReturnValue = cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.BigInt); 
        parmReturnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue; 
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strFirstName; 
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@MiddleInitial", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strMI; 
        conMyData.Open(); 
        cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        l = (long)cmdInsert.Parameters("RETURN_VALUE").Value; 
    } 

    return l; 
}
```

Comment: This way you also do not have to send out an output parameter.